# How do I find the amount of months between 2 parameter fields in crystal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have 2 parameter fields, one for start date and one for end date. I need to find how many calander months are between them. ie 1/4/2013-4/30/2003 would be return 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateDiff("m", {Table.OlderDate}, {Table.YoungerDate}
```